# Rollback is not happening at all...why?

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have the below

```
Declare @tbl Table(Id int identity, SomeCol varchar(10) not null)

Begin Transaction Tran1
   Declare @ErrorNum int  
   Declare @i int   
   Set @i =1

   --Start Operation
   While(@i <= 10)
    Begin

        If(@i = 9)
            Begin
                Insert into @tbl(SomeCol) Values(null)
                Set @ErrorNum = @@ERROR
            End
        Else
            -- All records will be inserted successfully
            Begin
                Insert into @tbl(SomeCol) Values(@i)
            End
        Set @i = @i +1

    End -- End of while

    -- If there is any error, notify that and roll back the transaction
   IF @ErrorNum <> 0 
   BEGIN 
      RAISERROR ('Attempt to insert null value in [Phone Number] is not allowed',16,1) 
      Rollback Transaction Tran1
   End
IF (@ErrorNum = 0)
   COMMIT TRANSACTION Tran1

   select * from @tbl
```

What I am trying to do is that, if the value of @i is 9 , I am trying to insert a null value to the @tbl which should not allow at all and should rollback all the records and will generate only the custom exception.

But it is giving both system and custom exception and the records have been inserted and not rolledback except for the 9th record.

The below is what I got in the Message Tab

```
**(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 14
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'SomeCol', table '@tbl'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 29
Attempt to insert null value in SomeCol is not allowed
(9 row(s) affected)**
```

And the below is in the Records tab

```
Id  SomeCol
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
10  10
```

I am not sure what wrong I have done.

Help needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table variables don't get rolled back. Try using a `#temporary` table instead and your script should work as expected!

```
create  Table #tbl(Id int identity, SomeCol varchar(10) not null)

Begin Transaction Tran1
   Declare @ErrorNum int  
   Declare @i int   
   Set @i =1

   --Start Operation
   While(@i <= 10)
    Begin

        If(@i = 9)
            Begin
                Insert into #tbl(SomeCol) Values(null)
                Set @ErrorNum = @@ERROR
            End
        Else
            -- All records will be inserted successfully
            Begin
                Insert into #tbl(SomeCol) Values(@i)
            End
        Set @i = @i +1

    End -- End of while

    -- If there is any error, notify that and roll back the transaction
   IF @ErrorNum <> 0 
   BEGIN 
      RAISERROR ('Attempt to insert null value in [Phone Number] is not allowed',16,1) 
      Rollback Transaction Tran1
   End
IF (@ErrorNum = 0)
BEGIN 
   PRINT 'COMMIT'
   COMMIT TRANSACTION Tran1
END
   select * from #tbl

drop table #tbl
```

Comment: that's fine.. I have used #temp table now. and it worked. But I only want to generate the custom message. I am getting  (1 row(s) affected)
....
(1 Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 14
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'SomeCol', table 'tempdb.dbo.#tbl__________________________________________________________________________00000000000C'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
Attempt to insert null value in [Phone Number] is not allowed

(0 row(s) affected)

Comment: @user. Not sure if/how to suppress that in 2000. Later versions you can use `TRY ... CATCH`

Comment: @user.  I think Martin's right.  See try...catch example below.  This suppresses the first error message and only issues the custom error message.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are never get to 
`Rollback Transaction Tran1` - since RAISE appears before.
Just swap both lines

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following to the begining of your script then the entire transaction will be rolled back on failure (no partially loaded table variable), but you might not see your custom error message:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
```

From the Microsoft [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx):

> When SET XACT_ABORT is OFF, in some
>   cases only the Transact-SQL statement
>   that raised the error is rolled back
>   and the transaction continues
>   processing. Depending upon the
>   severity of the error, the entire
>   transaction may be rolled back even
>   when SET XACT_ABORT is OFF. OFF is the
>   default setting.

If you'd like the transaction to be rolledback and to issue your custom error messasge, you could use Try...Catch:

```
BEGIN TRY
    Declare @tbl Table(Id int identity, SomeCol varchar(10) not null)

    Begin Transaction Tran1
       Declare @i int   
       Set @i =1

       --Start Operation
       While(@i <= 10)
        Begin

            If(@i = 9)
                Begin
                    Insert into @tbl(SomeCol) Values(null)
                End
            Else
                -- All records will be inserted successfully
                Begin
                    Insert into @tbl(SomeCol) Values(@i)
                End
            Set @i = @i +1

        End -- End of while

        COMMIT TRANSACTION Tran1

       select * from @tbl
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
       BEGIN 
          RAISERROR ('Attempt to insert null value in [Phone Number] is not allowed',16,1) 
          Rollback Transaction Tran1
       End
END CATCH
```

Comment: but that never gives the custom error. I am getting(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 16
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'SomeCol', table 'tempdb.dbo.#tbl___

Comment: Fixed link to MS documentation. Specify location of XACT_ABORT in script.

Comment: Added try...catch example.  I believe this does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Table variables cannot be rollbacked. [See here.](http://databases.aspfaq.com/database/should-i-use-a-temp-table-or-a-table-variable.html)